# RoR: Destroy association with has_many, :through if orphaned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Given [Ryan Bates's great tutorial on Virtual Attributes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes), how would I go about destroying a Tag (not Tagging) if, once the article is destroyed, that Tag is no longer used?

I tried doing something like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   after_destroy :remove_orphaned_tags

   private

   def remove_orphaned_tags
     tags.each do |tag|
       tag.destroy if tag.articles.empty?
     end
   end
end
```

... but that doesn't seem to work (the tags still exist after the article is deleted, even though no other article uses them). What should I be doing to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `remove_orphaned_tags` method, what is "tags" that you do an `each` on?

Wouldn't you need like `Tag.all` ?

Comment: Thanks; I guess I had assumed `tags` was `self.tags`, which probably wouldn't have worked anyway (oh, sleep deprivation...).

Answer (score 3):

JRL is correct. Here is the proper code.

```
 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    after_destroy :remove_orphaned_tags

    private
    def remove_orphaned_tags
      Tag.find(:all).each do |tag|
        tag.destroy if tag.articles.empty?
      end
    end
 end
```

Comment: Have you considered the performance implications of cleaning up your tags every time an article is deleted?

You might want to consider a cron job running an sql script to accomplish this.

Comment: It depends on the application. If articles are deleted only occasionally, then it may be more efficient than running the task on a set schedule!

Also, since he's working in Rails, I would recommend a Rake task set to a cron job so as to keep the app consistent and packaged.

Answer (score 0):

i know it's way too late, but for people who encounter the same issue,
this is my solution:

```
 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    around_destroy :remove_orphaned_tags

    private

    def remove_orphaned_tags
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          tags = self.tags # get the tags
          yield # destroy the article
          tags.each do |tag| # destroy orphan tags
            tag.destroy if tag.articles.empty?
          end
        end
    end

 end
```